# Не работает enter в редактировании меток

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, метки

1. <kbd>Править метки</kbd>
2. Начать писать метку, нажать стрелку вниз и выбрать подходящую (нажав на ней <kbd>enter</kbd>)
3. Попытаться нажать <kbd>enter</kbd> для применения изменений

Пункт 3 не срабатывает.

Comment: А как должно работать? У меня добавляется метка что под курсором. Вы не написали ожидаемое поведение.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, этот enter относился к "выбрать подходящую". Я про следующий enter, который должен применять изменения. Дополнил.